# How to find the largest word from the string using C#?

Tags: c#, string

This is my code for finding the largest word from a given string. I have got the length of all the words in the string now how do I get the largest word to be printed out?  I have tried to get all the largest words but am not able to do using this code plz help?

```
using System;
using System.Linq; 
class largest1{
    public void largest(){
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the String:");

        string buffer1 = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] buffer = buffer1.Split(' ');
        int length;
        string largestword = buffer[0];

        for(int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++){
            string temp = buffer[i];
            length = temp.Length;

            if( largestword.Length < buffer[i].Length ) {
                largestword = buffer[i];
            }
        }

        var largestwords = from words in buffer
                            let x =  largestword.Length
                            where words.Length == x 
                            select words;

        Console.Write("Largest words are:");      
        foreach(string s in largestwords){
            Console.Write(s);
        }
    }

    static void Main(){
        largest1 obj = new largest1();
        obj.largest();
    }
}
```

Comment: @spidy Sorry for editing the code when u were replying.. what are the two things which are wrong?

Comment: Here's whats wrong. When you do your second for loop, buffer3 stores the word at index i. 

So imagine your words are "This" "is" "four" "long". Your longest word is "This" (4 characters long) and "four" and "long" are the same length. When you loop through the second time, you store "This" at index 0, "four" at index 2, and "long" at index 3. There is nothing stored at index 1 because "is" is not the same length as the longest word. You need two index variables. 

Add int j = 0 outside the loop. And add j++ inside the if statement.

Comment: That 
"for words in list where words.length == largestword.length select words;"
also works

Comment: i tried what you said but I get this output Largest Words are long.Largest Words are long.Largest Words are long.Largest Wor
ds are long.long.Largest Words are long.Largest Words are long.Largest Words are
 long.Largest Words are long.Largest Words are long.Largest Words are long.Large
st Words are long.Largest Words are long.Largest Words are long.Largest Words ar
e long.Largest Words are long.Largest Words are long.Largest Words are long.Larg
est Words are long.Largest Words are long.Largest Words are long.

Comment: Whats wrong with the code I provided below? I tested that, and it works fine

Comment: @sorry I have lost my code trying to edit things can you please post your code which worked fine. Thanks

Comment: It's down below under my answer.

Comment: the one which you gave at the beginning right?

Comment: The part under **EDITED**. Copy that entire class, then use that class in Main

Comment: @spidy yeah that works can you identify the mistake in this edited at the beginning.

Comment: foreach is the same as a for loop. That's why the string is printed everytime. Put Console.WriteLine("Largest words are:"); outside the foreach. Put Console.WriteLine(s); inside the foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Put this in your class so that it is persisted
string largestword = "";

//Put this right before your for loop
largestword = buffer[0];

//Put this inside your for loop
if( largestword.Length < buffer[i].Length ) {
     largestword = buffer[i];
}
```

**EDITED: Added support for multiple words of the same length**

```
class LargestWordsClass
{
    public LargestWordsClass()
    {
        _LargestWords = new List<String>();
    }

    //This says that the variable can be set from the class but read by anyone
    public int LargestWordSize
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    //This lets users get the list without being able to modify it
    private List<String> _LargestWords;
    public String[] LargestWords
    {
        get
        {
            return _LargestWords.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public void FindLargestWord()
    {
        _LargestWords.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the String: ");
        String buffer = Console.ReadLine();
        String[] splitBuffer = buffer.Split(' ');

        LargestWordSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < splitBuffer.Length; i++)
        {
            if (LargestWordSize < splitBuffer[i].Length)
            {
                LargestWordSize = splitBuffer[i].Length;
                _LargestWords.Clear();
                _LargestWords.Add(splitBuffer[i]);
            }
            else if (LargestWordSize == splitBuffer[i].Length)
            {
                _LargestWords.Add(splitBuffer[i]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The word is " + splitBuffer[i] + " and the length is " + splitBuffer[i].Length.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The largest word" + ((_LargestWords.Count > 1) ? "s are" : " is:"));
        for (int i = 0; i < _LargestWords.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_LargestWords[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if two words have the same length? I must be able to print both those words?

Comment: I have tried something can you see and tell where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 6):

use Max to get this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class MainClass {
    public static void Main() {
        string[] words = { "cherry", "apple", "blueberry" };

        int longestLength = words.Max(w => w.Length);

        Console.WriteLine("The longest word is {0} characters long.", longestLength);
    }
}
```

Comment: @spidy:ok i agree. you gave him the right answer. But this is more elegant way to get the length of maximum word.Then you can do anything.

Comment: What if 2 words have the same length ?

Answer (score 4):

Alrighty, here is a nice clean way using LINQ to take a list of string, and return a list of the longest ones. (test is assumed to be an `IEnumerable<string>`

```
        var ordered = test
            .GroupBy(str => str.Length)
            .OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Key)
            .First()
            .ToList();
```

The explanation:

1. We group the list using the length of the strings. This will return an `IGrouping` with a key of type `int` which is the length of the string in that group.
2. We then order them so the largest key (string lengths) is on top
3. We then select that group.
4. (Optional) Project it to a list. You can just use this `IGrouping` in a foreach loop without needing to run `ToList()`

Enjoy!

Comment: I have edited the code by following ur technique plz help me in tht?

Comment: @user561730: I'm not sure what you mean. Feel free to just use this exact code I have given you.

Comment: Now the question has been edited using ur idea and could you see what mistake I have done it that ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void largest(){

 Console.WriteLine("Enter the String:");
 string buffer1 = Console.ReadLine();
 string[] buffer = buffer1.Split(' ');
    int length;
    /*foreach (string word in buffer)
    {
    //Console.WriteLine(word);
    }*/
        string temp = string.Empty;
    for(int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++){
        if(temp.length = buffer[i].length)
            temp = buffer[i];         
}
Console.WriteLine("The word is " + temp + " and the length is " + temp.length.tostring());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string[] words = { "berryblue", "cherry", "apple", "blueberry" };
int maxLength = words.Max(s => s.Length);
var longestWords = from word in words where word.Length == maxLength select word;
foreach (var word in longestWords) System.Console.WriteLine(word);
```

Answer (score 0):

Condensed linq version:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the string:");
    string[] words = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    var longestWords = words
        .Where(w => w.Length == words.Max(m => m.Length));
    Console.WriteLine("Longest words are: {0}", 
        string.Join(", ", longestWords.ToArray()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Testingstring
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s,s2;
            s2 = " ";
            char[] a = new char[]{' '};
            Console.WriteLine("Enter any string");
            s = Console.ReadLine();

            foreach (string s1 in s.Split(a))
            {
                if (s2.Length < s1.Length)
                {
                    s2 = s1;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The largest string is " + s2 +" and its length is " +s2.Length);
            Console.ReadKey();



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a short description for a sample code to improve the post accuracy :)

Answer (score 0):

take look at my solution

it uses a `Dictionary` to store the `words` with there `lengths`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var longestWord = LongestWord("Hello Stack Overflow Welcome to Challenge World");

        PrintTheLongestWord(longestWord.Key);

    }

    public static KeyValuePair<string, int> LongestWord(String statement)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> wordsLengths = InitializeDictionary(statement.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

        return GetMax(wordsLengths);
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, int> InitializeDictionary(string[] wordsList)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> wordsLengths = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        foreach (var word in wordsList)
        {
            wordsLengths[word] = word.Length;
        }

        return wordsLengths;
    }

    private static KeyValuePair<string, int> GetMax(Dictionary<string, int> dictionary)
    {
        KeyValuePair<string, int> max = new KeyValuePair<string, int>(" ", Int32.MinValue);
        foreach (var item in dictionary)
        {
            if (item.Value.CompareTo(max.Value) > 0)
                max = item;
        }
        return max;
    }        

    public static void PrintTheLongestWord(string word)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"the Longest word is {word} with length {word.Length}");
    }  
}
```

and here is another solution with `one loop`

```
 public static string LongestWord2(String statement)
    {
        string max = "";
        foreach (string word in statement.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            if (word.Length>max.Length)
            {
                max = word;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
```